# PhoneGap Build, Hydration and Plugins

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins

I'm trying out building my first PhoneGap app, the hydration feature seems really nice. But every time I enable it when I have a plugin added in my config.xml the build fails and the following message shows:

```
plugman install --platform android --project //app/dist --plugin //c036732a-a4a5-11e3-81e8-22000a98b3d6": sh: line 7: plugman: command not found
```

If i disable the plugin or disable hydration everything works again. Im using version 3.3.0 and this syntax to include plugins as indicated in the manual:

`<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera"/>`

I've tried with multiple plugin and everything ends with a similar result. Anyone got any pointers to what I could be doing wrong?